# Writing itertools results to csv output

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I have run the following code to list every possible permutation of 10-bit binary:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ["".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=10)]
```

How can I get the results to print in a standard csv format?

So:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
```

etc?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try use `','.join(seq)` instead of `''.join(seq)`, this should separate each value with comma

Comment: @xbb even if the answer is simple, maybe you should write that as such and not as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write the sequences to a file you can use the following:

```
f=open('foo.csv','w')
f.write('\n'.join(",".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=10)))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for s in (",".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=10)):
    print s
```